# Is there a way to always fire up my express VPN app whenever I open an incognito tab in chrome?

Tags: chrome-for-android, vpn, openvpn

Is there a way to always fire up my express VPN app whenever I open an incognito tab in chrome?

Basically something like a batch file or shell script maybe that can trigger this?

Comment: MacroDroid can run shell scripts, but i believe it can not capture the triggering event

Comment: The problem is in detecting the incognito mode by end users. Some apps such as SwiftKey are able to guess/know the incognito mode but I don't think any end user solution exists for detection unless somebody copies the logic and provides it to us.

Answer (score 3):

When you open incognito tabs in chrome, there is a notification that appears with the message "Close all incognito tabs". You can use it to automate the process of launching your app.

Using [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate):

1. In the Interface section, select the Notification posted block. Click on it, select chrome as the package and set Chrome as the title on the Input arguments section. In the output arguments section, set x (or any name).
2. In the General section, select the Expression true? block. Click on it and set "Close all incognito tabs" as the formula.
3. In the Apps section, select App start. Click on it, select your app in the package section.
4. Link the block as seen on the image below.
5. Save the macro. Grant Automate the Notification Access permission. Click Start.

When you open an incognito tab in  Chrome, when a Notification with the title Chrome appears, if the notification has "Close all incognito tabs", the app selected in step 3 will start.

**Note:** I don't have your app installed. So I stopped my demonstration at step 3. You could play with other blocks for instance to click at some part of the screen to click a button, minimize the app, go back to chrome after opening it, etc.

[image: IMG:]